# Is it possible to reinitialize OneSignal?

Tags: reactjs, web, onesignal, i18next

I want to localize OneSignal push prompt using i18n, but can't figure out is there a way to reinit. Because only on OneSignal init I can set custom prompt text.
I'm using web sdk.

Here is an example how I configure OneSignal custom prompt:

```
OneSignal.init({
          appId,
          safari_web_id,
          promptOptions: {
            slidedown: {
              prompts: [
                {
                  type: 'push',
                  autoPrompt: true,
                  text: {
                    actionMessage: t('common.actionMessage'),
                    acceptButton: t('common.acceptButton'),
                    cancelButton: t('common.cancelButton'),
                  },
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        });
```

Comment: Why do you want to re-init?  Are you expecting your user is changing their language or something, so the i18n values change, so you want to re-initialize OneSignal?  I don't see anything in the API that enables "tearing down" OneSignal and allowing re-initialization. So if this is the case, you might need to prompt the user to "refresh your browser" (or programmatically do so) if they change their language to force a reload of the whole app.-